# Re-arrange NSArray/MSMutableArray in random order

Tags: iphone, random

I'm using NSArray/NSMutable array to store different objects.
Once all the objects are added, I want to re-arrange them in random order.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
NSUInteger count = [yourMutableArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
// Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
   int nElements = count - i;
   int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
   [yourMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

Answer (score 27):

```
// the Knuth shuffle
for (NSInteger i = array.count-1; i > 0; i--)
{
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(i+1)];
}
```

Comment: Best solution if you target your app iOS >= 4.3. `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3)`

Comment: why do you iterate from n -> 0 and not 0 -> n

Comment: @Peter He iterates backwards because he doesn't want to get the count at every iteration and the direction doesn't matter since we're randomizing it anyway. Keeps the line count down.

Answer (score 1):

Link GameplayKit/GameplayKit.h in your project then

```
#import <GameplayKit/GameplayKit.h>
```

Now you can use the property shuffledArray.

```
NSArray *randomArray = [yourArray shuffledArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let count = self.arrayOfData.count
for (index, _) in self.arrayOfData.enumerated()
{
  let nTempElement = count - index
  let swapIndexwith = (Int(arc4random()) % nTempElement) + index
  arrayOfData.swapAt(index, swapIndexwith)
}
```