# How to randomize an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, shuffle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone - nsarray/nsmutablearray - re-arrange in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202102/iphone-nsarray-nsmutablearray-re-arrange-in-random-order)

I have an NSMutableArray that contains 20 objects. Is there any way that I could randomize their order like when you shuffle a deck. (By order I mean their index in the array)

Like if I had an array that contained:

1. **apple**
2. **orange**
3. **pear**
4. **banana**

How could I randomize the order so that I could get something like:

1. **orange**
2. **apple**
3. **banana**
4. **pear**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's some sample code:
Iterates through the array, and randomly switches an object's position with another.

```
for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {
    int randInt = (arc4random() % ([array count] - x)) + x;
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:x withObjectAtIndex:randInt];
}
```

Comment: THanks for this simple code. It works. I love you man.

Answer (score 4):

```
@interface NSArray (Shuffling)

- (NSArray *)shuffledArray;

@end

@implementation NSArray (Shuffling)

- (NSArray *)shuffledArray {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[self mutableCopy] autorelease];

    [newArray shuffle];
    return newArray;
}

@end

@interface NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSUInteger count = [self count];

        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSUInteger j = arc4random() % (count - 1);

            if (j != i) {
                [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

However keep in mind that **this kind of shuffling is [merely pseudorandom](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) shuffling**!