# How to shuffle NSMutableArray without repetition

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Here in my code I want to shuffle the elements in the array and try to print it out, but it's not shuffling properly, I tried what is shown  [here](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/19/objective-c-how-to-shuffle-a-nsmutablearray/).Its working but,it values are repating.

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    { 
        button= (UIButton *)view;
        if (button.tag >=1 && button.tag <=20)
        {
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                [texts rotate];
                // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
                int nElements = count - i;
                int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
                [texts exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
                //int myTag= j+1;
                //button = [self.view viewWithTag:myTag];
                name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[texts objectAtIndex:n]];
                [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSLog(@"current  name :%@",name);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

After shuffling the array values are repeating,pls help me to solve this issue

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it not shuffling?

Comment: … and [iphone - nsarray/nsmutablearray - re-arrange in random order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202102/iphone-nsarray-nsmutablearray-re-arrange-in-random-order).

Comment: … and [how to randomize an NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255369/how-to-randomize-an-nsmutablearray).

Comment: If you don't think any of those solves your problem, please edit your post to explain exactly what you're seeing that you think is incorrect output.

Comment: @8vius its not print its shwoing error

Comment: Adding the error to the question might give people a better idea of the problem.

Comment: Instead of if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||..||button.tag == 20), why cant you use if (button.tag >=1 && button.tag <=20)? Short and simple. Easy to understand. Also what exactly is the error with above code?

Comment: @ACB i update the code in my question, here now the probem problem is repeatation of array contents

Comment: @8vius i update the quest part pls help me

Comment: So my understanding is that you want to shuffle texts once and then assign the objects in that shuffled array to the buttons in self.view subviews, right? And you dont want to have buttons having same name and it should be unique. is that correct?

Comment: @ACB exactly that is what i want

Comment: Raise it as a new question. It is not exactly about shuffling the array. Your problem is that button names are repeating. I think due to the question title, they have closed it.

Comment: @ACB here i detailed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227350/shuffle-nsmutablearray-without-repeatation-and-showing-in-a-uibutton pls try to get me the solution yaar

Comment: @fasilmoham Sure, I will add the answer there..

Answer (score 0):

Try this `int n = (arc4random() % count);` 
 instead of 
    `int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;`
 
Ensure that you are swapping current element with any element in the `texts` instead of an element which is always succeeding it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the category of NSMutableArray

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (ArrayUtils)
-(void)shuffle
{
static BOOL seeded = NO;
 if(!seeded)
{
    seeded = YES;
    srandom(time(NULL));
}

NSUInteger count = [self count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

}

Comment: NSMutableArary *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];    [arr shuffle]; its easy